# Getting value using BeginInvoke/Invoke

Tags: c#, multithreading

I was trying to get the row count of a DataGridView [ dataGridView1.Rows.Count ]. I found out that the row count is still 0 when though the UI shows multiple rows added already in the DataGridView. I figured out that this might be a threading thinggy so I used the following code to retrieve the row count :

```
public void OnTagsReported( ... )
{
  ...  

  for( var i = GetDataGridViewRowCount( dgvScanResult ) - 1; i >= 0; i-- )
  {
    var row = dgvScan.Rows[ i ];
    ...
  }  
  ...
}

protected int GetDataGridViewRowCount( DataGridView gridView )
{
  try
  {
    if( ! InvokeRequired )
    {
      return gridView.Rows.Count;
    }

    var count  = 0;
    var action = new Action<DataGridView>( delegate( DataGridView c ) 
                 { count = c.Rows.Count; } );

    gridView.Invoke( action, gridView );

    return count;
  }
  catch( ObjectDisposedException ) {}
  catch( InvalidOperationException ) {}
}
```

I get the row count but was wondering if this is the correct way. May I know how would ya'll do it?

Thank you all for your kind attention and opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why is your OnTagsReported method in another thread? Anyway, two comments.

First: Yes you can do it like that, but in GetDataGridViewRowCount is an error. You should call InvokeRequired also on the gridView because you are using gridview.Invoke later on.

Second: Better call your OnTagsReported method in the correct thread. Then you don't need the GetDataGridViewRowCount method.

```
public void OnTagsReported()
{
  if (dgvScanResult.InvokeRequired)
  {
    dgvScanResult.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(OnTagsReported), null);
    return;
  }

  for( var i = dgvScanResult.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i-- )
  {
    var row = dgvScan.Rows[ i ];
    ...
  }  
  ...
}
```